# How do you completely delete a VM from Windows 10 Hyper-V Manager?

Tags: windows, virtual, hyper-v

There does not appear to be an obvious way to do this.  If no such workflow is possible using the Hyper-V Manager, how do you do it via other means?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and tried many suggested ways but nothing worked.
Eventually, I solved it siply by pressing ALT+CTRL+DEL -> tasks -> search for "virtual" (or disk or hyper) and just killed the process.
And then you can delete the files without any issues from File explorer...

Answer (score -2):

The workflow may not exist within the Hyper-V Manager GUI provided by Microsoft.  However, by simply running

```
Remove-VM "<VM Name from Hyper-V Manager>"
```

from within the Windows PowerShell will delete the target VM.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/remove-vm?view=win10-ps

Comment: `remove-vm` does not delete virtual hard disks. so first get all hard disks `Get-VM –VMName XYZ | Select-Object VMId | Get-VHD` then run `remove-vm` and last delete the vhds